# Revoke em TEMPORARY TABLE no PostgreSQL, é possível?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql

É possível dar um `REVOKE` (Remoção de privilégio) para que os usuários não criem tabelas temporárias?
O `CREATE TABLE` eu preciso manter, porém, preciso bloquear o `TEMPORARY TABLE`.

É possível?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 3):

```
REVOKE TEMPORARY ON DATABASE seuSB FROM usuario
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/DML/Revoke.sql).

[Documentação](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-revoke.html).

Comment: Ótimo, eu vi esse comando em https://postgrespro.com/docs/postgresql/9.5/sql-revoke.html mas não consegui montar.

Comment: Me retratando,  o comando acima esta certíssimo.

Comment: Não disse que estava errado, apenas não consegui hehe.

Answer (score 0):

revogando o create;

```
REVOKE CREATE ON SCHEMA public FROM user;
```

revogando o temporary

```
REVOKE TEMPORARY ON DATABASE userdb from user;
```

Obs: A tabela Temporary, só existe enquanto o usuário que fez a conexão  a criou e permanecer conectado no final da conexão ela e removida pelo banco;

```
CREATE [ [ GLOBAL | LOCAL ] { TEMPORARY | TEMP } ] TABLE nome_da_tabela
    [ (nome_da_coluna [, ...] ) ]
    [ WITH ( parâmetro_de_armazenamento [= valor] [, ... ] ) | WITH OIDS | WITHOUT OIDS ]
    [ ON COMMIT { PRESERVE ROWS | DELETE ROWS | DROP } ]
    [ TABLESPACE espaço_de_tabelas ]
    AS comando
```

para visualizar seu SCHEMA  utilize o comando \dt exemplo abaixo:

```
Esquema  |  Nome   |  Tipo  |   Dono   
-----------+---------+--------+----------
 pg_temp_8 | t1      | tabela | alex
 public    | pessoas | tabela | alex
```

Sendo assim o comando de REVOKE TEMPORARY, fica assim:

```
REVOKE TEMPORARY ON DATABASE userdb from alex;
```

O SCHEMA é temporário, então não faz sentido pegar o objeto SCHEMA.

E se o usuário for SUPERUSER | DBCREATE, ele vai continuar criando tabela temporary;

O comando sera necessário ALTER ROLE;

```
ALTER ROLE alex WITH NOSUPERUSER NODBCREATE;

 select * from pg_user where pg_user.usename = 'alex';
 usename | usesysid | usecreatedb | usesuper | userepl | usebypassrls |  passwd  | valuntil | useconfig 
---------+----------+-------------+----------+---------+--------------+----------+----------+-----------
 alex    |    16384 | f           | f        | f       | f            | ******** |          |
```

Com todas as alterações seu usuário não vai conseguir criar  a TEMPORARY.

FORÇANDO CASO NENHUMA DAS DICAS ACIMA FUNCIONAR;

```
 REVOKE ALL ON DATABASE template0 FROM PUBLIC; 
 REVOKE ALL ON DATABASE template1 FROM PUBLIC; 
 REVOKE ALL ON DATABASE seudb FROM seuuser;
```

Estou colocando isso devido a dificuldade que pode ocorrer; O porque do comando porque os Privilégios de acesso user=Cc/user sera de user; Não de template0 ou template1; porque template0 tem privilégio de postgres=Ctc/postgres

O comando \l no psql ajuda a visualizar, mas teste cada caso e um caso depende da configuração do seu banco postgre.

Comment: O duro que não funcionou. ERRO: tipo de privilégio TEMP é inválido para esquema

Comment: olhe se seu SCHEMA é publico, e se nesse SCHEMA seu usuario tem uma role |SUPERUSER  e mude para | NOSUPERUSER   e | NOCREATEDB

Comment: @L.Gustavo melhorei a resposta da uma olhada pra ver se resolve seu problema.